# GnuPlot Axis info with Binary Data

Tags: gnuplot

I am currently working with a C/C++ program that performs some signal processing and writes data to a file and commands to a pipe for a GnuPlot process to ingest.  Essentially my data is a one-shot spectrum and an STFT spectrogram.  Given that my data is in contiguous array in memory, I would like to be able to output the X-Axis information, Y-Axis information followed by the data it self, however I can't seem to work out the appropriate command format for GnuPlot.  In addition, I'd like to keep my data as double precision if possible (mostly for connivence to prevent additional data casting, but it can be done if necesary)

Below is the command currently used to generate the plot (which doesn't support the axis information):

```
// Send command to the pipe to generate the plot
fprintf(commandPipe, "plot '%s' binary format=\"%%float64\" array=(%d,%d)  with image title \"Channel 2\" \n",  chan2_fileName, dataWidth , dataHeight  );
```

Which ideally could be followed by the following:

```
// Send X-Axis info to the data file
fwrite(xData, sizeof(double), dataWidth, dataFile);
// Send Y-Axis info to the data file
fwrite(yData, sizeof(double), dataHeight, dataFile);
// Send the spectrogram data
fwrite(spectrogram, sizeof(double), dataWidth * dataHeight, dataFile);
```

Any Thoughts / suggestions of how I might be able to make this work?

Thanks!
TMII